# Add subdocument for each document in array dynamically

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I want to `$addField` for every document in a sub-array with the name as `arrayName_index` (don't know how long the array is).

For example:
I have a collection of fun activities that looks like:

```
{
  _id: "1", 
  activity: movie,
  attendees: [
    {firsName: "personA", lastName: "lasty"},
    {firsName: "personB", lastName: "namey"},
    {firsName: "personC", lastName: "blabla"}
  ]},
{
  _id: "2", 
  activity: bowling,
  attendees: [{firsName: "personA", lastName: "lasty"}]
}
```

I want a MongoDB aggregation to create output as:

```
{
  _id: "1", 
  activity: movie,
  attendees: [
    {firsName: "personA", lastName: "lasty"},
    {firsName: "personB", lastName: "namey"},
    {firsName: "personC", lastName: "blabla"}
  ],
  attendees_1: {firsName: "personA", lastName: "lasty"},
  attendees_2: {firsName: "personB", lastName: "namey"},
  attendees_3: {firsName: "personC", lastName: "blabla"},
},
{
  _id: "2", 
  activity: bowling,
  attendees: [{firsName: "personA", lastName: "lasty"}],
  attendees_1: {firsName: "personA", lastName: "lasty"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit long and complex query.

**Concept**

**1.0** `$replaceRoot` - Replace the input document to specific document

**1.1** `$mergeObjects` - Merge current document (`$$ROOT`) with the object generated in 1.2.

**1.2** `$arrayToObject` - Convert array to single document from 1.3.

**1.3** `$reduce` - Iterate each element from the array and transform it to a single value.

**1.4** `$concatArrays` - Merge array.

**1.4.1** Create document with

**1.4.1.1** `k` (key) with prefix "attendees_" and get the index of current iterate document (`$indexOfArray`) + 1.

**1.4.1.2** `v` (value) with current iterate document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            "$arrayToObject": {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": "$attendees",
                "initialValue": [],
                "in": {
                  "$concatArrays": [
                    "$$value",
                    [
                      {
                        k: {
                          "$concat": [
                            "attendees_",
                            {
                              "$toString": {
                                "$add": [
                                  {
                                    "$indexOfArray": [
                                      "$attendees",
                                      "$$this"
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  1
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        v: "$$this"
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DXxpasuGnIt)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe slightly better since this avoids array searches, but it's largely the same as Yong Shun's answer.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            "$arrayToObject": {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": { "$range": [ 0, { "$size": "$attendees" } ] },
                "initialValue": [],
                "in": {
                  "$concatArrays": [
                    "$$value",
                    [
                      {
                        k: {
                          "$concat": [
                            "attendees_",
                            { "$toString": { "$add": [ 1, "$$this" ] } }
                          ]
                        },
                        v: { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$attendees", "$$this" ] }
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4ooaRumzLKC).